# Помогите php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Помогите пожалуйста, есть скрипт и всё такое, он выводит новости из ДБ, мне надо что бы была возможность, добавлять в таблицу лайк, типо имеется 1 лайк, он выводиться из таблицы, и при нажатие на кнопку, добавляется еще лайк. таблица называется post в таблице раздел с лайками like

```
<input type="image" src="system/img/ic_like_active_24.png" name="add_like"/>
```

Comment: php код напишите, который у вас есть сейчас. Здесь помогут, но за вас делать не будут

Comment: Отредактируй вопрос, дополнив его своим кодом.

Comment: А в чем проблема у вас возникла, вперед.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добрый день.

Информации, конечно, мало, но я думаю в самом простом варианте поможет что-то вроде этого:

```
UPDATE post SET like = like + 1 WHERE id = {$articleId}
```